# BHO Plugin (Microsoft JScript runtime error)

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, internet-explorer, bho

I have built a BHO (Browser Helper Object) in C# which detects phone numbers in web pages and places an image with a hyperlink next to it. The BHO basically inserts a javascript which uses a Regex String to find phone numbers and adds the image next to it.

This is the relevant code

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
        HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;

        IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)
        document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

        IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject =
        (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
        scriptObject.src = "\nhttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js";
        ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);

        IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject2 =
        (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
        scriptObject2.text = "\nwindow.onload = function()"+
                                                "{"+
                                                      "$('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d\\d\\s\\d\\d\\d)/g,'$1 <a href=\"http://www.somewebsite.com\"><img src=\"image.png\" border=\"0\"></a>') );"
                                                +"}"+
                               "\n\n";
        ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject2);
}
```

I have tested the BHO in IE on a very simple page with few phone numbers. It works as expected. But when i test the BHO with any other page on the web i get the following error

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

or

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied**

I am getting Microsoft JScript runtime error for a few other pages. Does this mean that i am not allowed to insert a javascript into the page ? What could be the reason ? I hope this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors are thrown because you add jQuery multiple times to the site you're loading. Have you ever tried to set a breakpoint inside the OnDocumentComplete method? 
If you do so, you will see, that the OnDocumentComplete event is fired more than one time, per site request.

So you should check at first, if it's the first time the OnDocumentComplete event is fired for the actual site request. If so, add you javascript, if not, do nothing.

This should prevent double jQuery includes.